# I am not able to handle date Validation using HTML5, date input in reactjs,

Tags: html, reactjs

This is my code below. I am not able to bind date in html5 input using Reactjs please help

```
<div className="form-group pl-4 pr-4">
                <label for="moduleName">Start Date </label>
                <input
                  type="date"
                  id="startDate"
                  name="startDate"
                  className="form-control rounded-0"
                  defaultValue={this.props.data.startDate}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeStartDate}
                />
              </div>
```

Comment: what error you are facing???

Comment: could you explain what you expect it to do ?

Comment: I am unable to bind the date value to date control, it shows 'dd/mm/yyyy', though the API is returning date string, it works good with text input but date control doesn't bind date

Comment: @JatinParmar I am unable to bind the date value to date control, it shows 'dd/mm/yyyy', though the API is returning date string, it works good with text input but date control doesn't bind date